# i can't to open telegram , whatsapp , facebook,twitter links in a flutter webview?

Tags: android, flutter, webview, share, whatsapp

I created a Flutter webview application...I have a share option in my application. when I click WhatsApp share it does not navigate to the external whats app. it's going page Not Found. I want to open an external application. How to handle this task in a flutter to support Android? I used the flutter webview plugin to launch a URL. My flutter webview version 2.3.1

Comment: if url launcher opens a page it's not a code problem. have you checked if you are using the correct url?

Comment: https://tamilnadunow.com/wow-facts >> am using this URL only. I added queries too but did not navigate to whats app. I checked with both flutter webview and url_launcher.. my flutter webview version 0.3.3

Comment: I updated the webview version also still am in the same stage. any solution?

Answer (score 2):

In short, do this, maybe it will help you:

```
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart'; 

// ...

    WebView(
      initialUrl: 'https://example.com',
      navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
        if (request.url.contains("mailto:")) {
          canLaunchUrl(Uri(
                  scheme: 'mailto', path: 'you@example.com'))
              .then((bool result) {
            launchUrl(
              Uri(scheme: 'mailto', path: 'you@example.com'),
              mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,
            );
          });
          return NavigationDecision.prevent;

        } else if (request.url.contains("tg:")) { // TELEGRAM
          canLaunchUrl(
                  Uri(scheme: 'tg', path: 'resolve?domain=YourId'))
              .then((bool result) {
            launchUrl(
              Uri(scheme: 'tg', path: 'resolve?domain=YourId'),
              mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,
            );
          });
          return NavigationDecision.prevent;

        }

        return NavigationDecision.navigate;
      },
    ),

// ...
```

Html links:

```
<a href="tg:resolve?domain=YourId">Telegram (YourId)</a>
<a href="mailto:you@example.com">Email (you@example.com)</a>
```